# Any alternative to the indexOfAny method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the index of a char that splits two numbers, the char can either be +, -, / or *. I'm making a simple calculator.

The process would be extremely trivial if i could use the indexofAny method, because i would be able to check for all 4 values in 1 line. Sadly, it's not available in Java.

NOTE: I do not want to use indexOf, since i would have to write 4 lines of nearly identical code.

**My main class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static MathUserInput readInput() {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] parts = input.split("\\+|-|/|\\*");
        int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        char operation = input.charAt(1);

        return new MathUserInput(firstNumber, secondNumber, operation);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("This is a calculator.");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Please provider a number, an operator and a number");
        System.out.println();

        MathUserInput input = readInput();
        char operation = input.getOperation();

        switch (operation) {
            case '+':
                System.out.println(input.getFirstNumber() + input.getSecondNumber());
                break;

            case '-':
                System.out.println(input.getFirstNumber() - input.getSecondNumber());
                break;

            case '*':
                System.out.println(input.getFirstNumber() * input.getSecondNumber());
                break;

            case '/':
                System.out.println(input.getFirstNumber() / input.getSecondNumber());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently using a switch statement, but i'm hoping that there's a better alternative. Essentially, i'm aiming to only have 1 line that outputs the result in the calculator.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be possible with the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). In essence, we would define an interface for the operations, realize four implementations of this interface and choose the according implementation based on the operator we find in the expression.

Comment: @Turing85 Ah i see, haven't learned about Interfaces yet, or patterns in general. I can definitely look into it, thank you.

Comment: You can always write a method like : evaluate(firstNum, secondNum, operator) and you don't even need a switch. The method can decide what to do with operator or an illegal operator even.

Comment: Out of the box in Java, this feels like a good use case for a regex pattern matches solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`StringUtils#indexOfAny(CharSequence, char...)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) from Apache Commons Lang which does exactly what you want.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public static MathUserInput readInput() {
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    int pos = StringUtils.indexOfAny(input, '+', '-', '/', '*');
    return new MathUserInput(input.substring(0, pos), input.substring(pos + 1), input.charAt(pos));
}
```

If you don't want to include a library for this, you can always write your own utility. Have a look at the code of StringUtils to be inspired. They are basically looping over the characters of the input string and in a nested loop over the characters to be found. The index of the first match is then returned.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use enum for the operations and encapsulate logic in it:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

        System.out.println("This is a calculator.");
        System.out.println("Please provider a number, an operator and a number");

        MathUserInput input = readInput(scan);
        System.out.println(input.execute());
    }

    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<a>[^+\\-*\\/]+)(?<operation>[+\\-*\\/]+)(?<b>[^+\\-*\\/]+)");

    private static MathUserInput readInput(Scanner scan) {
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(scan.nextLine());

        if (!matcher.matches())
            throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect expression");

        double a = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group("a").trim());
        double b = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group("b").trim());
        Operation operation = Operation.parseSign(matcher.group("operation").trim().charAt(0));

        return new MathUserInput(a, b, operation);
    }

    private static final class MathUserInput {

        private final double a;
        private final double b;
        private final Operation operation;

        public MathUserInput(double a, double b, Operation operation) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.operation = operation;
        }

        public double execute() {
            return operation.execute(a, b);
        }

    }

    private enum Operation {
        SUM('+', Double::sum),
        SUBTRACTION('-', (a, b) -> a - b),
        MULTIPLY('*', (a, b) -> a * b),
        DIVISION('/', (a, b) -> a / b);

        private final char sign;
        private final BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> func;

        Operation(char sign, BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> func) {
            this.sign = sign;
            this.func = func;
        }

        public final double execute(double a, double b) {
            return func.apply(a, b);
        }

        public static Operation parseSign(char sign) {
            for (Operation operation : values())
                if (operation.sign == sign)
                    return operation;
            throw new EnumConstantNotPresentException(Operation.class, Character.toString(sign));
        }

    }

}
```